# Como obtener el valor de un DataTable aplicando LINQ

Tags: c#

¿Como obtener el valor de un campo de un DataTable?
He logrado obtener el valor de una campo de un DataTable de la siguiente manera.

```
var strSQL = "SELECT Id, Descripcion FROM Mensajes";
var dt = GetAll(strSQL);
string result = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Pero aplicando LINQ lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no lo consigo.

```
string result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Descripcion")).ToString();
```

Comment: El valor teniendo en cuenta alguna condición de algún campo? sí es así cuál sería? podría usar `AsEnumerable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta queriendo obtener el valor de la primer row, si usas solo el Select() devuelves una lista, entonces debes aplicar el First()

```
string result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Descripcion")).First();
```

Si quieres seguir con tu tecnica podrias hacer

```
var descriptions = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Descripcion")).ToList();

string result = descriptions[0];
```

en este caso obtienes la lista de descripciones y de esta el primer item

Comment: Hola Leandro, me quedo usando el First(), gracias!!!